# How to remove drag effect when moving a Slider in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-slider

I'd like to remove the drag effect from the slider tick and I move it.
I don't want to have this light purple circle in the image below.

[image]

I'm aware of `interactionSource` param in the `Slider` component but I'm not handling it properly to remove/disabled the drag effect.

Here is my actual code:

```
var sliderWeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
Text(text = sliderWeight.toString())
Slider(value = sliderWeight, onValueChange = { sliderWeight = it }, interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a parameter to define the halo color or the halo radius, but you can provide a custom [**`LocalRippleTheme`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ripple/package-summary#LocalRippleTheme()) to override the default behaviour.

Something like:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
    Slider(
        value = sliderWeight,
        onValueChange = { sliderWeight = it },
    )
}

private object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not work for there have any other idea how can I achieve this ?

Comment: also i am using Material 3 slider